# matching empty row with regex and skipping

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to implement regex match for empty string coming from csv file which has last column consisting of row number

eg: `"","","","","","","","","",5`

The regex pattern which i am using is as `(\W*\d\W)` though for now it is working but in the longer run i am not sure whether it will fulfill the requirement of checking empty row with last column as Digit.

Could some better pattern be suggested. I am still new to regex.

Comment: `(\"\"\,)+\d+$` ?

Comment: Thanks Slavik, but its not able to match it.

Comment: I did updated my pattern and came up with (^(\"\",)+?,?\\d+?,) Any Suggestion for the same. This is passing most of the valid scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need a regex to match an empty string. Java has a special method for that [isEmpty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty()). Just call it on a string that you want to check:

```
String str = ...;
if (str.isEmpty()) {
  // do something if the string is empty
} else {
  // do something if the string is not empty
}
```

Now the reason why your regex does not work is because you match: 
\W* - zero or more non word character
\d - any digit (0-9)
\W - one more non word character

This will match something completely different. Your regex will match sequences like:

> [[[[[9]

You can read more about semantics of these regex symbols mean [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

If you want to match an empty String with regex you can try the following regex:

> ^$

Which means:

^ - match beginning of a line
$ - match end of a line

This will only match a line that has nothing between beginning of it and end of it which is an empty line.